# Questions related to collision

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

I have a few questions related to collision:

1. Is coefficient of restitution($e$) only defined for velocities along common normal in an oblique collision?
2. Can conservation of momentum only be applied along the common normal if no external force is acting?
3. The 2nd question leads up to a bigger question that is - can conservation of momentum be applied for velocities in more than one direction at the same time.

For example, if two bodies are colliding obliquely, can conservation of momentum be applied for initial and final velocities in any direction or at a time we can only apply it in the x-direction...

Is $(P_{x_{initial}}= P_{x_{final}} \text{ and } P_{y_{initial}} = P_{y_{final}})$ or $(P_{x_{initial}} + P_{y_{initial}} = P_{x_{final}} + P_{y_{final}})$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, coefficient of restitution is only defined for velocities along common normal in an oblique collision.
2. When no external force is acting, the vector sum $\sum \vec p$ must be constant. So it's not only along common normal, momentum is conserved along any direction. This also answers (3).

Comment: What do you mean by any direction? Conserving momentum along all directions together or conserving momentum along one direction at a time?

Comment: I have edited the question...Please clarify the last line in the question...

Comment: Oh nevermind, I just noticed that they are the same thing...